# Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: '=', received: 'P'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am working with aws cli cloudformation. While using the JSON parameters file along with yml template, I keep getting the error. I tried using create stack update stack as well as the change set.

```
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: '=', received: 'P' for input: 
- ParameterKey: FunctionName 
  ^ 
  ParameterValue: taskaplambda 
- ParameterKey: MemorySize 
  ParameterValue: 512 
- ParameterKey: Timeout 
  ParameterValue: 5
```

Where my command is:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name apstack --template-body file://templates/cflambdatemplate.yaml --parameters file://params/param.json
```

And my param.json is:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "FunctionName",
        "ParameterValue": "taskaplambda"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "MemorySize",
        "ParameterValue": 512
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Timeout",
        "ParameterValue": 5
    }
]
```

This is my YAML file

cflambdatemplate.yaml

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  tasklambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref FunctionName
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: !Ref MemorySize
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - "tasklambdarole"
          - "Arn"
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: !Ref Timeout
      CodeUri: 
        Bucket: taskapbucket
        Key: apbuild/lambda_function.zip

  tasklambdarole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
  taskPolicies: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties: 
      PolicyName: "root"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - 
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles: 
        - 
          Ref: "tasklambdarole"

Parameters:
  FunctionName:
    Type: String
    MinLength: '3'
    MaxLength: '18'
  MemorySize:
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '128'
    MaxValue: '1024'
  Timeout:
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '1'
    MaxValue: '15'
```

I have been trying this with every possibility, but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Could you also post your yml file?

Comment: I've added that too. I tried using it in a console. And it is working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just able to create everything you needed through aws CLI:

[image: CLoudformation Stack]

I'm using the same yaml file and json template of parameter and not getting any error. Below is the only change that I did in param.json :

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "FunctionName",
        "ParameterValue": "taskaplambda"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "MemorySize",
        "ParameterValue": "512"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Timeout",
        "ParameterValue": "5"
    }
]
```

You need to convert the **Number** to **String**, It's because CloudFormation parameter types don't map to JSON types, so the CLI expects everything to be passed as string.